# While using sed command i receive the following error : Function cannot be parsed. Any Solutions or reason for this?

Tags: linux, unix, ant, sed

I need to replace a particular character in a text file with another character. For example, replacing "E" with "A":

> `Apple ice` → `ApplA Ica`

While executing `sed 's/E/A' < apple.txt > app.txt` I receive the error

> function cannot be parsed

Please help! I need to automate this using Antscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in Ant environment, you probably don't need to execute sed at all, but rather use Copy task with filter, or [ReplaceRegExp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) task.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <replaceregexp file="apple.txt" flags="g" match="e" replace="A"/>
</project>
```

This alters the file in place:

```
$ cat apple.txt
Apple ice
$
$ ant
Buildfile: build.xml

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
$
$ cat apple.txt
ApplA icA
```

Your example is strange with case (a|A, e|E). I'll assume that's typo.

Follow up: To declare encoding...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project>
    <replaceregexp file="apple.txt" encoding="utf-8" flags="g" match="Á" replace=" "/>
</project>
```

I tested this successfully. Before:

```
ApplA icA
ApplÁs icÁs
```

After:

```
ApplA icA
Appl s ic s
```

Comment: But while trying to replace special characters to another special character a error is displayed :

invalid byte 2 of 2-byte utf-8 sequence.

Is this a problem with encoding used?

Comment: When trying to replace A acute with space.

Comment: The transfer is from unix to windows. The encoding used in xml is utf-8

Comment: The ReplaceRegExp task has an encoding parameter to declare the encoding of the target file (otherwise JVM default encoding is used). Also, you should declare the encoding of your Ant build file, since you are including non-ASCII characters there. Finally, be sure that whatever tools you use to edit the build file and the target file maintain the declared encoding.

Comment: When i used iso 8859-1 encoding. It worked for windows to windows transfers but not working for unix to windows transfer.

Comment: The ReplaceRegExp does not transfer the file. It modifies it in place. Should you ask another question about transfer?

Comment: Not sure how you're transferring the files. Let's say you're using the Copy task to copy to a mounted file system. Are you specifying the relevant encoding attributes in the Copy task? Otherwise you will get JVM default encoding.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you... I am using replaceRegExp task to modify in the src and after it i am using a copy task to copy it to another system.

Answer (score 3):

You should terminate your `sed` command with a slash (`/`) and I guess you want to exchange *all* occurences of `E` with `A`? Then you have to add a `g` for a global substitution:

```
sed 's/E/A/g' app.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

`sed 's/E/A/g' app.txt`. You missed the trailing `/` (`g` means all occurrences),